# How AngularJs code can be made compatible to be viewed in IE9 browser?

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-9, ie-developer-tools

I tried X-UA-COMPATIBLE meta tag,,Console messages removing..,etc..
The problem is it works only when IE developer tools are enabled..
Is there any other way to make it work rather than the way I followed ?

Comment: Please show some code, and explain what is not working.

Comment: Its a result screen where i have to display a table of contents with player details having runs,balls faced,sixes,fours,dot balls,etc..from the database..Its working fine..but i need to view the result without enabling developer tools..in IE..

Comment: Thanks #B8vrede.. I found the fix..

Answer (score 1):

- IE9 has some issues in loading console messages written in the
  scripts. Once it is removed the code works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

angular supports ie9 - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

if you are struggling with a specific area then you might want to Google for a "polyfill" - a polyfill basically provides support code where a browser has not yet implemented a specific standard

also make sure you are using the latest version of angular if possible

Comment: I have referred this link earlier..and let me work on the polyfills..and let you know..